# Entity Framework Core: Must I include related entities to a query to perform Where() queries on them?

Tags: entity-framework-core

assuming i have the following database model:
[image]

assuming i'd like to get all ProductCategories that have at least 1 available Product, my query would be something like:

```
return (from cat in dbContext.ProductCategories
        where cat.Producty.Any(prod => prod.IsAvailable == true)
        select cat).ToList();
```

now my question is: must i also **include the related entities** i want to check in my query to make sure that the checks on the related entities are performed correctly? like for example

```
return (from cat in dbContext.ProductCategories
           .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        where cat.Producty.Any(prod => prod.IsAvailable == true)
        select cat).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you only need `Include` if you actually want to include the related entities in the end result. The `where` clause may be translated in SQL `JOIN` statements, but this has no effect on what is included.